# change background color Angular 2 dynamicaly

Tags: angular2-template

I am trying to change `background-color` dynamically in the angular template. Can anyone help to do it correctly

```
[style]="background: {{ Save.get(sectioncode+qno)[1] }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background': yourColorFromComponent}"> </div>
```